# Editing structures with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm having programming classes, and just like a few years ago, I'm kind of stuck and lost.

I'm trying to create and save structures to/from a file, and then select a specific one and edit it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct studentdata{
int student_number;
char student_name[40];
int student_id;
char student_address\[60];
int phone_number;
};

void main(){
FILE *p;
struct studentdata insert;
int edit_student;
int location;
struct studentdata change;
struct studentdata *edit;
edit = &change;

p = fopen("students.txt","a");

printf("Insert student\n\n ");
    printf("Student Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &insert.student_number);
    printf("Student Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &insert.student_name);
    printf("Student ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &insert.student_id);
    printf("Address: ");
    scanf("%s", &insert.student_address);
    printf("Phone Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &insert.phone_number);
    printf("\tData saved sucessfully.\n");

        fwrite(&insert, sizeof(struct studentdata), 1, p);
        fclose(p);


        p = fopen("students.txt","r+");

        while(fread(&change,sizeof(struct studentdata),1,p)){
        printf("Student Number: %d\n", change.student_number);
        printf("Student Name: %s\n", change.student_name);
        printf("Student ID: %d\n", change.student_id);
        printf("Address: %s\n", change.student_address);
        printf("Phone Number: %d\n", change.phone_number);
        if (feof(p))
                break;
        }

        printf("Please input the student number you want to edit:");
        scanf("%d",&edit_student);
        fseek(p, 0, SEEK_SET);
        system("cls");


        while(fread(&change,sizeof(struct studentdata),1,p)){

        if ( change.student_number == (edit_student) ){

                    location = ftell(p);

                setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                    printf("Current student name: %s\n", change.student_name);
                    printf("\New student name: ");
                    scanf("%s", &edit->student_name);
                    printf("Current Student ID: %d\n", change.student_id);
                    printf("\tNew Student ID: ");
                    scanf("%d", &edit->student_id);
                    printf(" Current Address: %s\n", change.student_address);
                    printf("\tAddress / CP: ");
                    scanf("%s", &edit->student_address);
                    printf("Current Phone Number: %d\n", change.phone_number);
                    printf("\tPhone Number: ");
                    scanf("%d", &edit->phone_number);

                        location = ftell(p);

                    fwrite(&edit,sizeof(struct studentdata),1,p);
                    fclose(p);
                    break;
        }
            if (feof(p))
                break;
        }
}
```

But considering how much time I've spent around this idea with tons of testing and not going anywhere, I'm even doubting I'm using the right logic anymore

I've tested plenty of suggestions I've found around the internet, but most likely, I'm always missing something, or something like that

I've tried using pointers, as that's the option that's supposed to work for doing this kind of stuff, but the data keeps on being saved on the end of the file instead of overwriting the memory positions where i'm trying to put the new data

For some weird reason right now even though i can see that i have more than 2 users saved in the file (when running the first input gathering user data), the fread is only printing 2

Which is weird because i'm using the same parameters in other files in which i'm running tests and they print all the file data

One more project in which stuff isn't working the way it should....

My problem is for example if i have 4 structures saved in the file, and i select the 2nd for editing (and i have verified that ftell tells me it's in the memory position that belongs to the 2nd struct)
When i edit it's data, and run fwrite, shouldn't it save the structure data in the position it's in at that time, and thus overwriting it?

Comment: `edit` is a  pointer to `struct studentdata`.  It contains the address of a struct.  If you want to write that struct, you would use `fwrite(edit, ...` instead of `fwrite(&edit, ...`

Comment: Per previous comment, review  fwrite(&edit, 1, sizeof(struct studentdata),p);   see  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm

Comment: You can't read/write structs directly into a file without proper serialization/deserialization. Otherwise the file will be completely non-portable and full of garbage data in the form of padding bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to improve on that code but going straight to what you are asking:

```
while(fread(&change,sizeof(struct studentdata),1,p))
```

On that line you are reading in a full student. This operation moves the index of the file to the position just AFTER the student you just read. Then you write the updated student to the file on that position (Just after the student you just read that was the one you wanted to modify).
You need to move the index in the file back before writing (Using fseek and the position you get from `ftell` before reading in the new student).
You will need to move the `fread` call to inside the `while` loop.

Comment: I've tried adding the fseek before the fwrite, and tested it



I used a file which had 4 users, i selected and edited the 3rd one, and the next time i've opened the file, it read only 3 users (although i could see the 4th when opening the file in windows)


I'm seeing the difference between the fread being there and inside the while (sorry i'm still kind of a noob in this)



I've added an fseek before the fwrite
fseek(p, -(long)(sizeof(struct studentdata)), SEEK_CUR);